# Drupal to Drupal Migration Across Servers

Tags: drupal, migration

I am in the process of migrating a D7 site from one server to another. I have successfully exported and uploaded the settings to the new site using Features, but I need to get the content over to the site as well. I've been looking at several modules to try and solve this problem, but I have not found anything suitable for this task. Please let me know if I am overlooking a really simple solution.

Thanks!

Mark

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution is to export a database dump and import it into your new server. You can do it wotj phpMyAdmin but I recommend using Drush.

This way you can simply do a database dump via:

```
drush sql-dump > ~/sql-dump-file-name.sql
```

and later import via:

```
drush sql-cli < ~/sql-dump-file-name.sql
```

Also copy your files directory from old server to new server which is located in /sites/default/files.

Answer (score 0):

I've successfully used the backup and migrate module for these tasks. True, creating a dump and then spooling the dump into the other database works, but this typically also copies all caches. 
The [backup_migrate](https://www.drupal.org/project/backup_migrate) module allows you save backups on your local server, but also to your hard disk, from where you can upload it again to the other site.
A neat thing here is that you can exclude tables, such as cache tables, which makes the transfer much faster.

Obviously you need a core installation on the other end, and the backup_migrate module already installed for this to work, but I assume that since you only ask about the db, you must have mirrored the file structure already (excluding the settings files).